# Use VBA to assign and locate a specific table in a docx file by a method other than number of table

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I have an access database I'm using to populate various docx templates.  The same table appears in these docx files, but it's location (in relation to other tables) is not the same in each file.  Is there a way to assign a label or a name to a table, such that the VBA can locate it by this means rather than by the normal table number?

Comment: To help answer your question it would help to describe exactly how (if you were doing this manually) you'd know which is the correct table when you're looking at each of the templates.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to index them through the `.Tables` collection is by ordinal. But, you could always pick one of the `Table` properties like `.ID`, `.Title`, or `.Descr` to build your own retrieval function.  Using `.ID` it might look something like this:

```
Private Function GetTableById(seeking As String) As Table
    Dim i As Long

    With ThisDocument
        For i = 1 To .Tables.Count
            If .Tables(i).ID = seeking Then
                Set GetTableById = .Tables(i)
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Function
```

Called like this:

```
Dim foo As Table
Set foo = GetTableById("bar")
If Not foo Is Nothing Then
    '...
```